# Tensor product on the homotopy category is exact functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Suppose we are dealing with $K(R-mod)$(Here R is assumed to be commutative) consider the tensor of two complexes defined as follows:

$$(\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})_n = \bigoplus_{i + j = n} \mathcal{A}_i \otimes_R \mathcal{B}_j \text{ and }$$

$$d_{\mathcal{C}_1 \otimes \mathcal{C}_2}^n(a_{i} \otimes b_{j}) = d^{A}_{i}(a_i) \otimes b_j + (-1)^i a_i \otimes d^{B}_{j}(b_j)$$

I checked that the tensor as defined is symmetric has a unit. However, I am having troubles checking it is exact specifically.

I don't understand what is the shift functor applied to the tensor product gonna be?

I mean I don't understand what is $(\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})_n[1]$?

Comment: Your ring is probably commutative, and you should be explicit about that. What do you mean by saying that the tensor product of complexes is exact?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I mean that it commutes with the translation functor, and it sends exact triangles to exact triangles.

Comment: That it commutes with translation follows immediately from the definitions of the tensor product and of the translation: with what do you have problems in doing that? On the other hand, it is not an exact functor.

Comment: I don't understand how does it commute with the translation. I don't understand what is the translation of the following complex? $(\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})_n[1]$ Also, is it an exact functor if we consider $K(R-Proj)$ that is homotopy category of finitely generated projective R-module?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say $K^{b}(R-Proj)$.

Comment: I think it works with $K^{b}(R-Proj)$ right @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez ?

Comment: Yeah it works I figured everything out thanks.

Comment: Please correct the body of the question and add an answer if you worked it out!

Comment: Yeah, I will add an answer once I write it down in latex. I will also edit the question.